# Passing parameter in hive is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

Passing parameter in hive is not working for me. My code:

```
hive> set x='test variable';
hive> ${hiveconf:x};
```

I get this error:

> FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:0 cannot recognize input near `''test variable'' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'`

Comment: Why don't you print it using `select ${hiveconf:x};` before executing?

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> ${hiveconf:x};
```

Will literally substitute `'test variable'`. so you're executing the command

```
hive> 'test variable';
```

which SHOULD result in an error, since that's not a command I've ever seen with SQL.

If you're trying to output the value of x, you just have to do

```
SET x;
```

If you want to use the value of x in a statement, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE tbl WHERE a=${hiveconf:x};
```

would run the command

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE tbl WHERE a='test variable';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
hive> set x='test variable';
hive> set;
```

You will see value of `x` variable among values of many variable.